# Adding check boxes in AmCharts

Tags: angularjs, amcharts, ammap

I am working o an AngularJs Application where I am using AmCharts.

```
 const writeemp = data => {
        const {
            total,
            employees,
        } = data;

        empChart.dataProvider = e;
        empChart.write('emp');
        empChart.validateData();
    };

    AmCharts.handleLoad();

    var configChart = function () {


        empChart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
        empChart.categoryField = "state";
        empChart.labelRotation = 90;

        var yAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
        yAxis.position = "left";
        empChart.addValueAxis(yAxis);


        empBarGraph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
        empBarGraph.valueField = "count";
        empBarGraph.type = "column";
        empBarGraph.fillAlphas = 1;
        empBarGraph.lineColor = "#f0ab00";
        empBarGraph.valueAxis = yAxis;
        empChart.addGraph(empBarGraph);
        empChart.write('empChart');


        $http.get(hostNameService.getHostName()+"/dashboard/employees/statecount")
            .then(response => writeemp(response.data));
    }
```

Code in html:

```
                   <div class='panel-body'>
                        <div id="empChart"></div>
                    </div>
```

This would return me the values of State on x-axis and count on y-axis. I wanted to add checkboxes which would filter my data in the chart. Each check box should represent the 'state' of the employee. If I uncheck a box then the data displayed should change in the chart. Can anyone let me know how I could achieve this.

Comment: Probably not a good idea to duplicate questions with very slightly different wording. I addressed the legend variant of your exact question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39176903/6106614). Creating a custom checkboxes will need similar handling in toggling the columns.

Comment: @xorspark Sure. I thought the check boxes is a different concept in AmCharts.