# Amcharts - displaying legend entry for each column?

Tags: javascript, amcharts

Consider this snippet: http://jsfiddle.net/ouLed1fp/

How to get a legend entry for each column? also, how to get the column name next to it? basically, I want a proper legend.

```
<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 355px;"></div>
<script>

var chart;

var chartData = [{
    country: "USA",
    visits: 4025,
    subdata: [
        { country: "New York", visits: 1000 },
        { country: "California", visits: 785 },
        { country: "Florida", visits: 501 },
        { country: "Illinois", visits: 321 },
        { country: "Washington", visits: 101 }
    ]},
{
    country: "China",
    visits: 1882},
{
    country: "Japan",
    visits: 1809},
{
    country: "Germany",
    visits: 1322}];


AmCharts.ready(function() {
    // SERIAL CHART
    chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
    chart.dataProvider = chartData;
    chart.categoryField = "country";
    chart.startDuration = 1;

    // AXES
    // category
    var categoryAxis = chart.categoryAxis;
    categoryAxis.labelRotation = 90;
    categoryAxis.gridPosition = "start";

    // value
    // in case you don't want to change default settings of value axis,
    // you don't need to create it, as one value axis is created automatically.
    // GRAPH
    var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
    graph.valueField = "visits";
    graph.balloonText = "[[category]]: [[value]]";
    graph.type = "column";
    graph.lineAlpha = 0;
    graph.fillAlphas = 0.8;
    chart.addGraph(graph);

    chart.addListener("clickGraphItem", function (event) {
        // let's look if the clicked graph item had any subdata to drill-down into
        if (event.item.dataContext.subdata != undefined) {
            // wow it has!
            // let's set that as chart's dataProvider
            event.chart.dataProvider = event.item.dataContext.subdata;
            event.chart.validateData();
        }
    });

    var legend = new AmCharts.AmLegend();
    chart.addLegend(legend, "legenddiv");

    chart.write("chartdiv");



});

</script>
```

Comment: See:https://stackoverflow.com/a/39176903/6106614 - the "updated" section has what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working using this: https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/generate-legend-markers-column/

```
/*
  Plugin to generate legend markers based on category 
  and fillColor/lineColor field from the chart data by using 
  the legend's custom data array. 

  The plugin assumes there is  only one graph object. 
*/
AmCharts.addInitHandler(function(chart) {
  //check if legend is enabled and custom generateFromData property
  //is set before running
  if (!chart.legend || !chart.legend.enabled || !chart.legend.generateFromData) {
    return;
  }

  var categoryField = chart.categoryField;
  var colorField = chart.graphs[0].lineColorField || chart.graphs[0].fillColorsField;
  var legendData =  chart.dataProvider.map(function(data) {
    var markerData = {
      "title": data[categoryField] + ": " + data[chart.graphs[0].valueField], 
      "color": data[colorField]
    };
    if (!markerData.color) {
      markerData.color = chart.graphs[0].lineColor;
    }
    return markerData;
  });

  chart.legend.data = legendData;

}, ["serial"]);

var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "marginRight": 70,
  "legend": { 
    "generateFromData": true //custom property for the plugin
  },
  "dataProvider": [{
    "country": "USA",
    "visits": 3025,
    "color": "#FF0F00"
  }, {
    "country": "China",
    "visits": 1882,
    "color": "#FF6600"
  }, {
    "country": "Japan",
    "visits": 1809,
    "color": "#FF9E01"
  }, {
    "country": "Germany",
    "visits": 1322,
    "color": "#FCD202"
  }, {
    "country": "UK",
    "visits": 1122,
    "color": "#F8FF01"
  }, {
    "country": "France",
    "visits": 1114,
    "color": "#B0DE09"
  }, {
    "country": "India",
    "visits": 984,
    "color": "#04D215"
  }, {
    "country": "Spain",
    "visits": 711,
    "color": "#0D8ECF"
  }, {
    "country": "Netherlands",
    "visits": 665,
    "color": "#0D52D1"
  }, {
    "country": "Russia",
    "visits": 580,
    "color": "#2A0CD0"
  }, {
    "country": "South Korea",
    "visits": 443,
    "color": "#8A0CCF"
  }, {
    "country": "Canada",
    "visits": 441,
    "color": "#CD0D74"
  }],
  "valueAxes": [{
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "position": "left",
    "title": "Visitors from country"
  }],
  "startDuration": 1,
  "graphs": [{
    "balloonText": "<b>[[category]]: [[value]]</b>",
    "fillColorsField": "color",
    "fillAlphas": 0.9,
    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "visits"
  }],
  "chartCursor": {
    "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
    "cursorAlpha": 0,
    "zoomable": false
  },
  "categoryField": "country",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "labelRotation": 45
  },
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }

});
```